# Multitasking iPhone manager

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I want to know  how I  manage the multitasking in iPhone,
So for example I want audio multitasking or counter.
I used the appdelegate method (applicationDidEnterBackground for example), but in general I don't understand how I have to manage multitasking in iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read the following: [App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). iOS 6 isn't really a multitask OS (as it will be iOS 7). You can only run in background the following kinds of process according to Apple Documentation in the link:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

If you want to execute some custom code in background, iOS allows you only 10 minutes of background execution (you can find how to do that in the same document, in the `Background Execution and Multitasking` section). After 9:55 minutes, a handler expiration block will be executed, which gives you five seconds to do some last time processing.

Hope it helps!